# Not able to trigger outgoing mail for mail id configured on Gsuite via outlook for desktop application

Tags: .net, email, outlook, google-workspace

We are using a .net based desktop application for last 10 years which triggers mail via outllook, when a record is updated in application.

Earlier it was through shared hosting working perfectly fine. Since, this year start we migrated mail services for the domain to Gsuite mail service.

After that we configured application to send mail via smtp for gmail as done earlier for shared hosting and was working perfectly. But for past 1 month it has stopped sending outgoing mail. We have tried smtp configuration but its  not getting triggered via outlook now.

Note that we have no issues in sending receiving mail through outlook. and mail trigger was also working fine with app. But it is not sending outgoing mail from our desktop application configured via outlook. We have not made any other changes.

We have also enables less secure app but no use. We are passing 3 parameters as earlier 
Port: 465 
smtp: smtp.gmail.com
mailid: abc@domainname.com
Password: password for mail id

Please help our alerts are affected and we are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If your Gsuite users want to use desktop clients, you need to enable Post Office Protocol(POP) or Internet Message Access Protocol(IMAP) access in the Gsuit admin console.

For more information, you could refer to this link:

[Turn POP and IMAP on and off for users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/105694?hl=en)

Comment: Have checked and it's on. not able to figure out what is missing.